# How to perform of complex import of custom data?

Tags: 8, importing-exporting

Probably, there will be several tasks where I will need to perform import custom data from CSV or XLS files to Drupal 8 taxonomy vocabulary.

Moreover, when importing data it will have to be modified in various ways, or even be assembled from several tables into one vocabulary. That is, it won't be import data "as is" and "one-to-one".

Thus far I have found the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module and the [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) module.

In Drupal 7 I mainly used the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module. But I suspect that for Drupal 8 most people are mainly using the [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) module, whereas the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) has been abandoned by developers.

Please share your experience about:

- which solution you use in such cases of complex data import ?
- how you solved such import challenges in Drupal 8

That should help me to decide which one is the best for the challenge I'm facing.

Comment: The title of your question sounds like a "poll", and the content of it seems like a "module recommendation request". Both are off topic on this site. Can you think of adapting your question to avoid it gets put on hold?

Comment: Ok, I will try to do it ...

Comment: I have changed it, but maybe I have lack of imagination ...
I hope that the new title will be acceptable

Comment: Ok, if you know how to edit the question to make it proper, I will be thankful to you.

Comment: I'm done. Please review my edit. Feel free to further adapt/correct/enhance as you want. If you don't like my edit, just perform a "rollback". For what it is worth: the question is no longer a request for module recommendations, nor is it a "which one is best"-poll. And it still leaves the door open for anybody to post yet another module recommendation. Here is the tricky part of getting used to this site: "Is there a module for it" is not an acceptable question (off topic), but "There is a module for it" is a perfectly acceptable question. Bonne chance! Ps: delete your first 2 comments?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, your variant of the question is better, than mine.

And finally will I read smart thoughts of experienced drupalers relatively migration ? :)

Comment: merci for the feedback. Not sure if mine is "better", from experience I only think it is a "better fit with the Rules of this site". Actually refining your question is a typical sample of how tough it is on this site to ask a ***good*** question which is not at risk of being put on hold. I'm still not 100% sure that that risk is gone, but do think it is reduced quite a bit.Fingers crossed you'll (soon?) receive good answers to it (I've to pass on that part, sorry).